# Create NSString with different memory

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created three string, that bind it data with method argument. However, i face issue that all of three string share same memory, therefore, it show the same text. Here is how i create it:

```
-(void)buildViewsWIithTitle:(NSString*)eventTitle{

    NSString *firstStr = @"";
    NSString *secondStr = @"";
    NSString *thirdStr = @"";
```

Next i set label text to all of this three string. I set it value like:

```
 thirdStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", eventTitle];
 secondStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", eventTitle]
 firstStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", eventTitle];
```

In console i output its memory just after creation:

```
NSLog(@"memory %p , %p , %p", firstStr, secondStr, thirdStr);

memory 0x109af82d8 , 0x109af82d8 , 0x109af82d8
```

Any idea how make memory address different for them?

Comment: Is there a reason they need to have different allocations?

Comment: why do u need the addresses in the first place?

Comment: Why? Because it doesn't matter!

Comment: It does indicate he's probably doing something silly, which could probably be avoided, rather than worrying about compiler-specific implementation details.

Comment: It's not easy to do, because NSString objects get special efficient storage so that equal strings get identical storage (thus there is only one copy that can be used throughout the program). Try using NSMutableString instead.

Comment: @Eiko: if somebody has questions about implementation details, most likely we are facing a [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Droppy what you mean silly? I got 3 different views created by single method that pass 3 different strings as argument. Thos strings are different from each other and suppose to be titles.

Comment: Just as I said in the rest of my comment.  You should not need to rely on the address of the object to get whatever it is working.

Comment: @matt thank you matt.

Comment: @Droppy thank you, i will probably think again of my architecture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using NSString for all 3 objects, which can't be mutated, The compiler will check the value of the string, which is the same empty to all  strings. The compiler will optimise the memory usage by pointing the same memory.

The iOS compiler optimizes references to string objects that have the same value (i.e., **it reuses them rather than allocating identical string objects redundantly**), so all three pointers are in fact pointing to same address.

If you used the NSMutableString, still it may point to the same object, but when you try to mutate the string, it will be copied to the new memory(Lazy memory allocation).

if you want the different memory for each string then you can allocate the memory then initialize the string, like

```
 NSMutableString *str1 = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@""]
 NSMutableString *str2 = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@""]
 NSMutableString *str3 = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@""]
```

**But note that NSMutableString is mutable.**

Comment: You are talking about the re-use of *constant strings*. The compiler will not check all other instances of `NSString` in order to find and re-use a string as that would take far too long, as I'm sure you're aware.

Comment: @Droppy thanks for the question & When u use the same string ""(Empty string) which can't be mutable & it located in the same scope(Stack), then it is valid to have the single object for reading. Here iOS may not check the complete file or programme but the current local method's stack, which will point to the single immutable object/string in the heap. if I have missed out anything, please update it, i'm excited to look on it. Thanks!

Comment: It's simply pooling of constant strings is all; it's an old feature, but is somewhat limited; for example calling a dynamic library method will return a non-pooled string as the data segment is located in the library, not the exe.

Comment: @Vijay-Apple-Dev.blogspot.com thank you, that will do!

Answer (score 1):

That's because your all string have address of `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", eventTitle];` and this is same for all strings.

For example if you will write below code in your viewdidload then you will get different memory address,

```
  NSString *firstStr = @"";
NSString *secondStr = @"";
NSString *thirdStr = @"";

thirdStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"eventTitle"];
secondStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"eventTitle"];
firstStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"eventTitle"];

NSLog(@"memory %p , %p , %p", firstStr, secondStr, thirdStr);
```

Because everystring has own memory and not pointing to any single string.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's some kind of compiler optimisation going on. It determines (correctly) that the strings are the same so it optimises while compiling. As soon as you change your code so the strings will not be the same and recompile then the compiler won't optimise those particular strings.

```
thirdStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"a %@", eventTitle];
secondStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"b %@", eventTitle];
firstStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"c %@", eventTitle];
```